# Triangulating a polygon with one hole

Tags: geometry, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying to triangulate a polygon with one hole using [Triangle project](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/triangle.html).

Does anyone have an example of feeding this algorithm with a polygon with a hole?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making a .poly file? What went wrong? http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.poly.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of of .poly file with a hole:

```
14 2 0 0
1 1 -1
2 1 1
3 .25 1.25
4 0 1
5 -.25 1.25
6 -1 1
7 -1 -1
8 -.25 -1.25
9 0 -1
10 .25 -1.25
11 .33 0
12 0 .33
13 -.33 0
14 0 -.33
14 0
1 10 1
2 1 2
3 2 3
4 3 4
5 4 5
6 5 6
7 6 7
8 7 8
9 8 9
10 9 10
11 11 12
12 12 13
13 13 14
14 14 11
1
1 0.0 0.0
```

There are three sections in the file: the polygon vertices, the polygon segments and the hole specification. The last line indicates that the point (0,0) lies in a hole in the geometry and triangles in those components will be removed by triangle.

In showme, this .poly file looks like this:

[image: polygon geometry]

The small "x" in the center indicates the location specified for the hole.

Meshing this with the command triangle `simple.poly -a0.06 -q20` gives the following result:

[image: resulting mesh]

Comment: the polygon is represented in c language using by array of points and array of segments.

Comment: How do you know where the hole is? Maybe there is some kind of convention on the orientation of the segments? Triangle needs an (x,y) location inside each hole: you will need to determine a suitable (x,y) for each hole based on your data.

Comment: The polygon is represented in c language by array of points and array of segments (I'm using the function "triangulate" in c language from Triangle project). I don't understand how to represent the segments by an array of integers. (I already know some locations in the hole - that's not the problem)

Comment: I believe the segmentlist member of triangulationio takes the same data as the .poly file. In the above example, segmentlist should be an array containing 10,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,11. And numberofsegments should be set to 14. The segments involved in the outer boundary and the hole are not distinguished in the segment specification -- all should be included.